# Perform repetitive task batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file, converters

I have a script that activates a program to convert .mf4 files into .csv files. It looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF 
TITLE CallConverter 
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "C:\CANape\Project\Merged Global Config 2013\CSVConvert.bat" %* && exit 
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Vector CANape 14\Exec\ 
CallConverter.exe -C:ascconv.dll -IF:ascconv.ini C:\Users\kymarsh\Desktop\Test\File.mf4 C:\Users\kymarsh\Desktop\Test\_PQR.csv 
exit
```

It works great if I am only looking at one file. Otherwise I have to manually change "File.mf4" to the next file in question.

What I would like it to do is point to a directory and convert all files with the .mf4 extension.

Can someone help me out with this?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF 
TITLE CallConverter 
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "C:\CANape\Project\MergedGlobal Config 2013\CSVConvert.bat" %* && exit 
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Vector CANape 14\Exec\ 
for %%a in ("C:\Users\kymarsh\Desktop\*mf4") do (
   CallConverter.exe -C:ascconv.dll -IF:ascconv.ini "%%~fa" C:\Users\kymarsh\Desktop\Test\_PQR.csv 
)
exit
```

try with [for loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)

Comment: This works as far as looking and trying to convert each file however it doesn't take each file name and apply it to the saved csv file, it just overwrites the one that currently exists each time. 

If it is converting a file named file_01.mf4 it saves it as _PQR.csv 

Can you take each filename that it looks at and name each conversion accordingly so that in the above you would get file_01.mf4 saving as file_01.csv and so on for each additional file? 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KyleMarsh replace `_PQR.csv` with `%%~na.csv`(`%%~na` is the filename without path and extension)